# univariate regression on decile ranks versus multivariate dummy variable regression "equivalent"

Tags: regression

Generally speaking,

Which types of problems might it be appropriate to use a univariate OLS regression where the predictor takes 1 of 10 decile ranks and the response takes 1 of 10 decile ranks (i.e. both are coerced into being uniformly distributed variables from 1 to 10)...

VERSUS...

Splitting up the univariate variable into 10 different (1,0) dummy variables representing inclusion/exclusion from a particular decile, in this case, omitting one of the 10 ten decile ranks to avoid the "dummy variable trap".

Thank you. 
Bryan

Comment: If your response is nominal / categorical you cannot use a (gaussian) linear model. You could try ordinal regression.

Comment: Response would be a decile rank. Predictors would be decile ranks.

Comment: I would not use either, but the first approach is simpler.